# SVN to Git migration using svn2git

Tags: git, svn, svn2git

Can I use `svn2git` to migrate only trunk and maintain history as well? If yes, how do I proceed with it. 
I tried with something like this :

```
svn2git repoPath/trunk --authors authors.txt
```

Do I need some additional parmas as well? It throws an error after looping through certain revisions:

```
command failed:
git checkout -f master
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot os tools calling themself 'svn2git', even git has a utility to do that.

But if you are using this [svn2git](https://github.com/nirvdrum/svn2git):

> 3 . The svn repo is NOT in standard layout and has only a trunk at the root level of the repo.
>
> `svn2git http://svn.example.com/path/to/repo --trunk trunk --nobranches --notags`